# Is possible to add dynamically a new :input to jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have added some input elements that are not part of the standard HTML input elements. For example, I have a "pinpoint image" where you can put "pins" by clicking on it. This image is defined by some HTML code like this:

```
<div class="pinpoint">
    <img src="..." alt="" title="" maxpins="10" />
</div>
```

The problem is that I cannot consider this new item as an jQuery :input like an `<input>`, `<textarea>` or `<select>`. I'm wondering if there is possible to add dinamically `div.pinpoint` to the jQuery :input set so I can run:

```
$(":input").hide()
```

to hide all inputs, including my pinpoint image.

Comment: Will this help you.?  http://www.jameswiseman.com/blog/2010/04/19/creating-a-jquery-custom-selector/

Comment: It's very interesting @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, in this article explains how to add new pseudo-selectors but don't tells how to overload the existing ones. I'll research a bit about it.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expressions testing the tags are defined as vars in the closure so you can't change them without modifying jQuery, which would be an incredibly bad idea.

And, more importantly, existing or future code relying on the `:input` selector may very legitimately rely on what it normally is. It looks like another bad idea to break their assumption.

But you have clean workarounds.

For example, you can define a string const :

```
var inputs = ':input,.pinpoint';
```

allowing you to do

```
$(inputs).hide()
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but I'm using inherited code and there are hundreds of places where I should have to do this. It will be a great time-saving and error-saving if I can use existent ":input" selectors

Comment: @Ivan Surely your IDE has _find_ and _replace_ ability?

Comment: Yes, but as you know find and replace is error-prone :) Anyway, I've found the way to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As @dystroy mentions changing the jQuery source is not usually a good idea, you can use the find and replace ability of your IDE for changing all the selectors. However if you have a reasonable need for changing the selector, you can manipulate the source. jQuery uses sizzle engine for selecting the elements, you can modify the [`:input` selector](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/sizzle/dist/sizzle.js#L1348):

```
"input": function( elem ) {
            return rinputs.test( elem.nodeName ) 
     /* + */       || elem.className.split(' ').indexOf('pinpoint') > -1
     /* +          && elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'div'; */ 
},
```

The `Array.prototype.indexOf` is not supported by IE8 and below.

Comment: Please, take a look into my own answer. It's not strictly necessary to modify jQuery source code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [the link](http://www.jameswiseman.com/blog/2010/04/19/creating-a-jquery-custom-selector/) @RajaprabhuAravindasamy has published in a comment and after some research, I've found how to do this by overloading the `:input` selector:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
    input: function(elem) {
        return /input|select|textarea|button/i.test(elem.nodeName) || 
               $(elem).is('div.pinpoint');
    }
});
```

Another interesting link to know which are the default pseudo-class selector expressions is [this](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/expr/) where you can find this list that I've used to update my custom `:input` selector:

```
animated=function (a){return c.grep(c.timers,function(b){return a===b.elem}).length}
button=function (g){return"button"===g.type||g.nodeName.toLowerCase()==="button"}
checkbox=function (g){return"checkbox"===
g.type}
checked=function (g){return g.checked===true}
disabled=function (g){return g.disabled===true}
empty=function (g){return!g.firstChild}
enabled=function (g){return g.disabled===false&&g.type!=="hidden"}
file=function (g){return"file"===g.type}
has=function (g,h,k){return!!o(k[3],g).length}
header=function (g){return/h\d/i.test(g.nodeName)}
hidden=function (a){var b=a.offsetWidth,d=a.offsetHeight,f=a.nodeName.toLowerCase()==="tr";return b===0&&d===0&&!f?true:b>0&&d>0&&!f?false:c.curCSS(a,"display")==="none"}
image=function (g){return"image"===g.type}
input=function (g){return/input|select|textarea|button/i.test(g.nodeName)}
parent=function (g){return!!g.firstChild}
password=function (g){return"password"===g.type}
radio=function (g){return"radio"===g.type}
reset=function (g){return"reset"===g.type}
selected=function (g){return g.selected===true}
submit=function (g){return"submit"===g.type}
text=function (g){return"text"===g.type}
visible=function (a){return!c.expr.filters.hidden(a)}
```